# Random subseries of harmonic series expected to converge, but how often does it?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Inspired by a previous question which I can't seem to find, what if we have

$$X = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}\cdot P\left(U(0,1)<\frac{1}{k}\right)$$
That is, each term of the series will be $\frac{1}{k}$ with probability $\frac{1}{k}$ and otherwise $0$. Then our expected value becomes:

$$E[X] = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}\cdot p(k) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k}\cdot\underset{prob}{\underbrace{\frac{1}{k}}} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2} = \zeta(2) = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

So expected value would be finite. But how to calculate the probability for convergence? Maybe the higher moments are so nasty that convergence still won't be ensured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $E[X]$ is finite then $X$ is almost surely finite. I.e., $P(X<\infty)=1$, so the series converges almost surely. (Think about it this way - if there's positive probability that $X=\infty$, then $E[X]$ cannot be finite.)